# Spring Reactive Repository: findById(ID) vs. findById(Publisher<ID>)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, project-reactor, reactive

What ist better to create a fully non-blocking REST-Service?

```java
Mono<T> findById(ID id);
```

or

```java
Mono<T> findById(Publisher<ID> id);
```

Is the second method less blocking?

Here is an example:

```java
@GetMapping
public Mono<UserProfile> getUserProfile(Mono<Authentication> authentication) {
     return reactiveUserProfileRepository.findById(
          authentication.map(auth -> auth.getName()));
}
```

Or is it good enough to use an object as parameter?

```java
public Mono<UserProfile> getUserProfile(Authentication authentication) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestbody) you can benefit from non-blocking reading when using `@RequestBody` and reactive types:

> Unlike Spring MVC, in WebFlux, the @RequestBody method argument
> supports reactive types and fully non-blocking reading and
> (client-to-server) streaming.